# How to use variable from customizer.php in customizer.js

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using postMessage for my customizer and trying to avoid repetitions in customizer.php and customizer.js How can I use the variable $css from customizer.php and include it in customizer.js to avoid repeating h1,h2,h3 etc. So right now it works like this:

**customizer.php code**

```
function my_styles_method() {

  wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-css.css'
  );

  $colors = array(
    'headings_color'     => get_theme_mod( 'wpt_heading_color' ),
  );

  $css_output = "{color: {$colors['headings_color']}; }";
  $custom_css = "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6";
  $css = $custom_css . $css_output;


  wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method', 21 );
```

**customizer.js code**

```
wp.customize( 'wpt_heading_color', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $( 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').css( 'color', newval );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally made it working. I simply forgot to add_inline_style. Great thanks to Weston Ruter for help.
So the final code is:

```
function my_styles_method() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-css.css'
  );

  $colors = array(
    'headings_color'     => get_theme_mod( 'wpt_heading_color' ),
  );

  $css_output = "{color: {$colors['headings_color']}; }";
  $selector = "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6";
  $css = $selector . $css_output;

  wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $css );
  wp_localize_script( 'wpt_customizer', 'MyStylesSelector', $selector );       
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method', 21 );


/**
 * Binds JS handlers to make Theme Customizer preview reload changes asynchronously.
 */
function wpt_customize_preview_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wpt_customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'wpt_customize_preview_js' );
```

Link for Gist - https://gist.github.com/DeoThemes/ae61a166d09dba4817fb6e6d0ce78c8f

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_add_inline_script()` to export the variable from PHP to JS. For example, in `my_styles_method` assuming that your `customizr.js` script has the handle `my-styles-customize-preview`:

```
wp_add_inline_script(
    'my-styles-customize-preview',
    sprintf( 'var MyStylesSelector = %s;', wp_json_encode( $custom_css ) ), 
    'before' 
);
```

Then you can modify for JS to be:

```
wp.customize( 'wpt_heading_color', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $( MyStylesSelector ).css( 'color', newval );
    });
});
```

Nevertheless, I suggest a better approach and that is to update the inline style element instead of setting the `style` for each element. For example:

```
wp.customize( 'wpt_heading_color', function( setting ) {
    setting.bind( function( value ) {
        $( '#custom-style-inline-css' ).text( MyStylesSelector + '{ color: ' + value + '}' );
    });
});
```

This is also a good candidate for using a custom selective refresh `Partial` that short-circuits the partial refresh request to the server and instead handles the rendering client-side by overriding the `refresh` method.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but I tried it and it's not showing any changes right now :)
Do I need to add wp_add_inline_style after wp_add_inline_script to output  custom css?

Comment: It outputs <script type='text/javascript'>
var MyStylesSelector = h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6;
</script>

Comment: Fixed. I forgot the call to encode JSON.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: Any solution to make it work?

Comment: Are you enqueueing your `customizer.js` script? I don't see that in your example code.

Comment: Please share the full plugin code you are working with as a Gist.

Comment: Yes, my customizer is enqueued, and it shows live changes, but after I hit save the changes are not saving.
Here is the code - https://gist.github.com/DeoThemes/ae61a166d09dba4817fb6e6d0ce78c8f

Comment: It may be because you are not enqueueing your JS at `wp_enqueue_scripts`. I forked your gist and added some fixes, although yours doesn't have all your code so I'm not able to verify that the changes fix the problem you are seeing: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/a5ce4e3848bc0a22f24587ec41081709